# More general representation theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group. A representation on a vector space is a group homomorphism $G \to GL(V)$ for some $k$-vector space $V$. More general on could replace $V$ by an $R$-module $M$ over a commutative ring and then maybe over a non-commutative ring and get $R$-representations of $G$. Now one could also take for example instead of modules an arbitrary set $X$ and a representation would be a group homomorphism $G \to \text{Aut}(X)$, where $\text{Aut}(X)$ is the group of bijective maps. So all have in common that it is a group homomorphism from $G$ into the automorphism group of some object in some category.

Finally one could take an arbitrary category $\mathcal{C}$ and object $Y \in \mathcal{C}$ and define a representation of $G$ as a group homomorphism $G \to \text{Aut}(Y)$.

Is there some book which studies representations in this generality? Or maybe representations in more "unusual" categories like graphs or others?

Comment: What you define is nothing more and nothing less than a (left) group action (on an object in a category, cf. Riehl's Category Theory in Context, Ex. 1.3.9). I don't have any literature to recommend, but using that term over "representation" might yield better results.

Comment: I See. The question actually does not really make sense.